# How to compare two DATES having varchar as datatype

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables table1 and table2

table1 having following columns `(id,date_reg,status)`

date_reg is a varchar data type having date format like this `(mm-dd-yyyy)`.

And  table2 having following columns`(id,uname,date_reg)`

date_reg is a varchar data type having date format like this `(mm-dd-yyyy)`.

I need a matched records with recent date (by compare `table1.date_reg` with `table2.date_reg` )

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the `date_reg` column is *not* a `DATE`?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  You should be able to just do a `join` on the two fields, if you are looking for equality.

Comment: i think people use to like `varchar` for `date` because operation on `varchar` are simple to handle than that of `date` type

Comment: You would probably have to use something like [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), but that'll get expensive incredibly quickly across alot of rows. Why are they not stored as a `DATE`?

Comment: If you have consistent fields, changing the column data (or at least inserting a new column and converting the data to a proper date) shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @rock321987 Sometimes, what seems easier at first proves to be much more difficult, annoying and cumbersome in the long run. It is often better to stretch a little more earlier on and then be able to coast with the groundwork already done.

Comment: You can convert the varchar to date: str_to_date(table1.date_reg, '%m-%d-%Y') and then compare it.

Comment: I have imported from excel. If I put it as a DATE datatype then the values are inserting like  this (0000-00-00,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,0000-00-00,..) in cloumn reg_date

Comment: Maybe look into using `DATE_FORMAT()` when importing, or some other method to get it into the correct format. The small hassle of changing it from `VARCHAR` to `DATE` now will _absolutely_ pay off in the future.

Comment: Dates stored as varchar and using standard collation still index chronologically as long as you store them in the same format as MySQL, with the year first, and zero padded, like yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table1,
     table2
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(table1.date_reg, '%m/%d/%Y')=STR_TO_DATE(table2.date_reg, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: It would have to be `'%m-%d-%Y'` to match his example.

Comment: I have tried this one, Still not comparing properly

Comment: What a problem in query? Have you got any error let me know.

Comment: results are not coming as expected.. I need a recent date from both so I have given like this `CASE WHEN  DATE(DATE_FORMAT(table1.date_reg,'%m-%d-%Y 00:00:00'))  <  DATE(DATE_FORMAT(table2.date_reg,'%m-%d-%Y 00:00:00')) THEN table1.date_reg ELSE table2.date_reg END recentDate `

Comment: any how I'll appreciate your answer.

Comment: Add `order by recentDate DESC`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with regex/text parsing in PHP, but the general strategy would be to split your two strings on '-', then compare the year, then the month, and then the day. In pseudo code:

```
if table1.year > table2.year:
    return table1.date
else if table1.year < table2.year:
    return table2.date
else:
    if table1.month > table2.month:
        return table1.date
    else if table2.month > table1.month:
        return table2.date
    else:
        if table1.day > table2.day:
            return table1.date
        else if table2.day > table1.day:
            return table2.date
        else:
            return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

use following if date format is same:

> select * from table1 left join  table2 ON table1.date_reg = table2.date_reg

or if you want to where condition then

> select * from table1 left join  table2 ON table1.date_reg = table2.date_reg where table1.date='06-05-2014'

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE()` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to turn your `VARCHAR` fields into a valid date you can use for comparison, for example:

```
STR_TO_DATE(table1.date_reg, '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Ideally though, **you don't want to do this**. It's not a solution, it's another problem that's being used to try and cover up an existing problem, your Dates are being stored as `VARCHAR` instead of as `DATE`.

**You would be far better off** changing your import code to import the dates from Excel (Or wherever you are importing from) into a correct `DATE` format for MySQL. If you are not sure how to do that, I'd suggest creating a new question with the code you're using to import the data, and ask how to format it in the correct way.